# How can we test that a class implements many interfaces?

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, interface

My question is about testing a class that implements many interfaces. For example, I have this class:

```
public class ServiceControllerImpl extends ServiceController implements IDataChanged, IEventChanged {

}
```

Now there are two ways for testing. The first is testing directly on the concrete class. That means the object type is the concrete class rather than the interface.

```
public class ServiceControllerImplTest {
    ServiceControllerImpl instance;
    @Before
     public void setUp() {
         instance = new ServiceControllerImpl();
         // you can bring this instance anywhere
     }
}
```

The second way is testing on the interface only. We must typecast this object to all interfaces it implements.

```
public class ServiceControllerImplTest {
    ServiceController instance;       // use interface here 
    IDataChanged dataChangeListener;

    @Before
     public void setUp() {
         instance = new ServiceControllerImpl();
         dataChangeListener = (IDataChanged) instance;
         // instance and dataChangeListener "look like" two different object.
     }
}
```

I prefer the second solution because maybe in future we can change the interface it implements to other objects, so using the concrete class might lead to failing tests in the future. I don't know the best practice for this problem.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yeah for testing an interface you test on the interface type. So your second solution is basically the way to go.

Comment: I'm sure the above comment gives the answer, but your question needs a little clarifying. When you wrote `dataChangeListener = (IDataChanged) dataChangeListener;` you meant `dataChangeListener = (IDataChanged) instance;`, right?

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth yes. I edited. thanks so much.

Comment: There is nothing to choose between these two implementations. NB `ServiceController` is not an interface. It's a base class.

Comment: The argument applies to any supertype, either interface or superclass.

Comment: @DaveSchweisguth In the general case, yes. In this case it only applies to base classes or interfaces that implement/extend the interfaces being tested. This is not a proper subject of a unit test in my view. A simple Generic specification for example would turn the whole thing into a compilation hurdle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I prefer second solution because in reality, maybe in future we can change the interface it implements to other objects, so force using concreted class maybe leads to fail test in the future.

I guess it will lead to failed tests anyway, because you usually test that assertions are true or false. The question is: Do that tests apply to any `IDataChanged` or do these assertions only apply to the `ServiceControllerImpl`?

If the assertions only apply to the `ServiceControllerImpl` it doesn't matter if you use an `IDataChanged` instead of an `ServiceControllerImpl`, because you must edit the test when you use another `IDataChanged` object - different assertions. The test will fail if you use another object.

The way you setup unit tests Itself gives you an answer. A unit test usually tests one class in isolation. This means that you mock the environment. But mocking the environment means that you know the dependencies of the class you test and this are implementation details. So your test is written on an implemtation basis rather than only the interface.

It's possible to write tests that only test an abstract api - like an interface. But this usually means that your tests are abstract too. E.g.

```
public abstract class SetTest {

    @Test
    public void addAlreadyExistentObject(){
        Set<String> setUnderTest = createSetUnderTest();
        Assert.assertTrue(setUnderTest.isEmpty());

        boolean setChanged = setUnderTest.add("Hello");
        Assert.assertTrue(setChanged);

        setChanged = setUnderTest.add("Hello");
        Assert.assertFalse(setChanged);

        Assert.assertEquals(setUnderTest.size(), 1);

    }

    protected abstract Set<String> createSetUnderTest();

}
```

You can then extend these abstract tests to test the api for concrete classes. E.g.

```
public class HashSetTest extends SetTest {

    @Override
    protected Set<String> createSetUnderTest() {
        return new HashSet<String>();
    }
}
```

In this case you can replace the implementation and the test must remain green.

But here is another example of an abstract api when replacing the object under test does not really make sense.
What about writing a test for all `Runnable`s?

```
public class RunnableTest {

     @Test
     public void run(){
         Runnable runnable = ...; 

         // What to test here?
         // run is invoked without throwing any runtime exceptions?
         runnable.run();

     }
}
```

As you can see it does not make sense in some cases to write tests in a way so that you can easily replace the object under test.

If an api like the `Set` api defines a concrete state handling you can write abstract tests that test this.

Answer (score 1):

JayC667 already correctly answered that it's best to refer to a class through its supertype(s) in tests of methods defined by those types. But I'd change the way you did that a bit to avoid casting:

```
public class ServiceControllerImplTest {
    ServiceController controller;
    IDataChanged dataChangeListener;

    @Before
     public void setUp() {
         instance = new ServiceControllerImpl();
         controller = instance;
         dataChangeListener = instance;
     }
}
```